# _googWcmGet Google AdWords Testing URL Parameters

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, google-ads-api

I know I have done this before. Just cannot remember how. For those that are familiar with Google AdWords ability to push a phone number for conversion tracking to your website, it employs the following function:

```
_googWcmGet
```

The support documentation tells the user to wait an hour and then search for their ad to test it. But, there is an easier way.

There is some URL parameter that you can append to the query string to fool the script into thinking it came from AdWords. Anyone know what that is? Forgot it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It took me a while to find the answer that I knew existed. It is due to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607431/googwcmget-callback-not-working-via-gtm-with-dynamic-phone-number/27825095#27825095) made by [dorian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1101713/dorian)

> helpful debugging mode which you can activate by appending
>   `#google-wcc-debug` to the URL of the page where you have activated
>   call tracking

and can be found on [stackoverflow in answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607431/googwcmget-callback-not-working-via-gtm-with-dynamic-phone-number)

So specifically for example `http://www.example.com/#google-wcc-debug`

Then you should see a little pop up window in the bottom left of the browser. Hint: Press the 'force' button to see the telephone numbers on your page change.

Comment: DUDE! That's it. You rock. Thank you thank you! If I could send you a giant chocolate chip cookie right now I would.